# Compare two date

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, datetime

I need compare two date. One is from databese, second is from now.

```
var dat = DateTime.Now;  
var bd = (from d in.... 
if (bd != dat)
```

Date (bd) in database is type "*date*" so have only data.
Date from now (dat) get data with hours so  *if (bd != dat)* cannot compare properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [DateTime.Today](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today.aspx) which will strip out hours.